# Land seized during war

Tags: international, laws-of-war

Say one day Country A attacked Country B, and this began a full blown war between the two countries.

During this war, Country B seized some of Country A's territory along their mutual border, and Country B ended up winning the war.

Now that the war has ended, is Country B required by some international law or law of war to return the seized land to Country A?

Does it matter that Country A started the war, *not* Country B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Country A and country B must do whatever they agree in the settlement of the conflict between themselves - returning or ceding of territory being one of these. Or they can disagree about these laying the seeds for further conflict.

The most recent example of this is Russia's seizure of the Crimea from Ukraine; which they *legitimised* by a plebiscite. AFAIK, Ukraine and the international community has not accepted this but neither are they doing anything about it - legally Crimea is still part of Ukraine, practically it is part of Russia.

Comment: So, if country A were to want the land back from country B, would country B be obliged by any law to return it?

Comment: Yes - but the practical question of how (you and what army) remains. Lots of things happen in the world that are not legal.

Comment: Oh. Could you please point me to a specific law that requires the land be returned?

Comment: The UN charter - it guarantees (more or less) the territorial integrity of its members.

Comment: So wouldn't country A deciding to wage war on country B (for the purpose of conquering country B's territory) also be breaking the law in the first place?

Comment: Yes see Russia v Ukraine, Iraq v Quwait, USA et al v Iraq, Germany, Italy & Japan v everyone. In state v state conflicts there is almost always a breach of the law somewhere by one or (usually) both sides the issue is - what are you going to do when a nation like the USA or Russia decides to act like a criminal - start throwing nukes around? International law *depends* on sovereign states accepting that they are subject to it - if instead they say "f*^k you" there is no authority that can compel them to.

Comment: Sorry to keep asking questions, but if say France starts a war with Spain, but Spain is successfully able to fight back and takes part of southern France. Once the war is over, does any law require Spain to return the parts of France that it took over during the war?--regardless of whether Spain wants to or not

Comment: Two willing countries can legally transfer territory. If Spain keeps the territory they are acting illegally. However, if France doesn't have the military power to stop Spain and no other country will intervene and this situation continues for long enough then at some indeterminate point that land will be Spanish and no longer French as and when the international community accepts the status quo as the new normal. Put it another way: if I steal your bike and you are not strong enough to take it back and the police will not help you then it is de facto my bike even if de jure it's still yours.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Do you know of a reference for the law that explicitly states that the land must be returned?

Comment: The Crimea is a bit of an unusual case, given that its inhabitants would almost certainly have still voted in favour of joining Russia even in an un-rigged plebiscite (although with a rather smaller margin).